# Android Studio Can't Find 80+ Resources

Tags: android, android-studio

When I imported my project to Android Studio from Eclipse, I received many similar errors that weren't there beforehand. They all say that there was no resource found that matches a certain name. I've practically scoured this site by now in an effort to find an answer, but I've had no such luck.

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "hess.jacob.spindoctor"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'support-v4', version: '21.0.+'
    compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'appcompat-v7', version: '21.0.+'
    compile files('libs/opencsv-2.3.jar')
}
```

Here's my (heavily shortened) error log:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 32.921 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1199: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.PopupWindow.ActionMode'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:43: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.PopupWindow'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:44: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator.White'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.PopupWindow.ActionMode'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:47: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.PopupWindow'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator.White'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowSmall'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:51: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.NumberPicker'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadge.WindowSmall'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView.White'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadgeSmall'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.ImageButton.NumberPickerUpButton'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadge.WindowLarge'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.TimePicker'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadge.WindowMedium'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1336: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1349: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1337: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1341: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1342: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1339: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1343: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1344: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1340: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1352: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1378: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1387: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1391: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1379: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1383: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1384: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1380: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1381: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1385: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1386: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1382: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1404: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1413: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1417: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1405: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1409: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1410: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1406: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1407: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1411: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1412: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1408: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:60: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:minorWeightMin'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:97: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:minorWeightMin'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:114: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.WebTextView'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:115: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:minorWeightMin'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1592: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:152: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowMedium'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:153: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.LockScreen'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.StatusBar.IntruderAlert'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:155: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.StatusBar'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1633: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1647: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1654: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:159: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1666: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base.DropDownItem'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1672: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:1694: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:173: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowLarge'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme.Dialog.AppError'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:175: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.TypingFilter'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:176: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.SlidingTabNormal'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:177: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.SubMenuPanel'.

C:\Users\Kids\AndroidstudioProjects\SpinDoctor\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.SearchResult'.
```

(I would've given the whole error log, but that put me way over the character limit. Either way, the point is still evident... I hope.) From what I've found so far, I can't seem to get an answer for this, and I can't continue until I get one.

Edit:
Here's my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hess.jacob.spindoctor"
    android:versionCode="21"
    android:versionName="5.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="hess.jacob.spindoctor.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="hess.jacob.spindoctor.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: If you go to File >> Project Structure >> Modules >> Sources --> are your directories (e.g. src folder) marked as sources ?

Comment: I don't even have a Sources folder under Modules. That's probably a problem.